# Typewriter Effect in Javascript for multiple texts

Tags: javascript

This is my Javascript function. My goal is that anytime I pass a text to this, it should display the text in the div in the typewriter effect.

```
function typeWriter(txt) {

    if (i < txt.length) {
        console.log(i);

        maindiv.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);

        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter,50,txt);
    }

}
```

This is my main() function

```
function main() {
  typeWriter("Hello World.");  //line1
  i=0;
  console.log("Hello World just got entered"); //line2
  i=0;
  typeWriter("This is fun."); //line3
}
```

**What is happening**
After "H" in the first text gets displayed, the control is getting passed onto line2 and then line 3 and so on.

**What I want:**
The div should display "Hello World" in type writer effect first. And then, it should add "This is fun" to the div in type writer effect.I want line2 to execute ONLY after line 1 and line 3 ONLY after line 2.
What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is Promises. To make things more difficult you need to execute promises sequentially.

```js
const mainDiv = document.querySelector(".main-div")

// wrap timeout in a promise
function type(c, ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            mainDiv.innerHTML += c;
            resolve()
        }, ms)
    })
}

// execute promises sequentially
async function typeWriter(txt, ms) {
    const characters = txt.split("")
     // for loop is key, forEach would not work
     for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        await type(characters[i], ms)
    }
}

// await each asynchronous function
async function main() {
    const ms = 500;

    await typeWriter("Hello, ", ms)
    await typeWriter("World", ms)
}

main()
```

```html
<div class="main-div"></div>
```